# Typescript : generic not inferred

Tags: typescript, kotlin, generics

I'm new to Typescript, coming from Java/Kotlin. I have this script :

```
class RequestMessage<ResponseType> {}
class NewOrderRequestMessage extends RequestMessage<OrderFilled | OrderCancelled> {}

async function sendMessage<T>(requestMessage:RequestMessage<T>): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        // ...
    })
}

(async () => {
    let requestMessage = new NewOrderRequestMessage()
    let result = await sendMessage(requestMessage)
})()
```

My problem is that result type is inferred as "unknown", while I expected it to be inferred to `OrderFilled | OrderCancelled`, as the parameter of sendMessage is a `RequestMessage<OrderFilled | OrderCancelled>`

Typically, in Java/Kotlin, the same logic makes `result` correctly inferred :

```
class Promise<T>()

open class RequestMessage<T> {}
class NewOrderRequestMessage : RequestMessage<Int>() {}

fun <T> sendMessage(requestMessage: RequestMessage<T>): Promise<T> {
    return Promise()
}

val requestMessage = NewOrderRequestMessage()
val result = sendMessage(requestMessage)
```

In this equivalent Kotlin script, result is inferred to `Promise<Int>`.

Why couldn't it be in Typescript ? Due to this unknown type, Typescript doesn't give me error at compilation when sendMessage returns a Promise of another type, giving me weird situations.. I expect response type to be OrderFilled or OrderCancelled, but sendMessage can actually resolve to a promise of a completely unrelated type without having any compilation error, which produces unexpected and unhandled exception at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS is not strongly typed language, its type system is about shape only.
That said `NewOrderRequestMessage` is no longer a generic.
If you cast it to `RequestMessage<OrderFilled | OrderCancelled>` then inferring will work just fine:

```
interface OrderFilled {

}

interface OrderCancelled {

}

class RequestMessage<ResponseType> {}
class NewOrderRequestMessage extends RequestMessage<OrderFilled | OrderCancelled> {}
type RequestMessageWithOrder  = RequestMessage<OrderFilled | OrderCancelled>

async function sendMessage<T>(requestMessage:RequestMessage<T>): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        // ...
    })
}

(async () => {
    let requestMessage: RequestMessageWithOrder = new NewOrderRequestMessage()
    let result = await sendMessage(requestMessage)
})()
```

Play with the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJQCbQGLADZ4QbIDeAsAFCUC%20lloksiK6WUAwnCEgUaXRVpUKCPHADO45ACUIARwCuEcWACyy8XADmEADyzxABwD2IcRAAqAT0MQAfKSGiJUgHIQA7q2izFytRraKBAAHpAgGFK%20SirqkkG63lC4vMQAPmiY0JzcEKkOJEJgNijR-nGaOgDqwGAAFknIyAC8MvIxAfE6iVnJ%20ITpmWw5PAN2AhJW3MgwCtxgwKbI5hEVCRZ2ABRQ7eWBOgBcZbH7ehsAlAfIAApQxgC2wOa6G-wUTU07YApQIMggnhud0ezw2m22ymMeAAbhAADTIHYAKwgCDA5xaBUoHxxyAA9HjkAA6EnYj7Uc40ASbSbTTYY5pY94fQhgRG7E5dCBXY6dSoQGr1RqtAEeZDuLy9XlrHT0slNVns8QKPBs1pwDxwWrLCCrU4Qvyc-mUwTnelAA)

Comment: Great ! Makes sense, thank you for you reactivity :)